# .ics call iPhone from webview applikation

Tags: iphone, webview, native, icalendar

**Discription:**

I'm working on a iphone application, where we have made one of the pages as a webview. On this page, we have a event list with a button "Add event to calender".

We have made this page as a webview, because our customer needs to update this list with new events.

The button "Add event to calender" is linking to a .ics file, with information about the event. This page is working fine in safari on the iphone, but when the page is being viewed from a webview the functionality disapears and it just keep on showing the loading spinner, with the result with a crashed app. :-/

**Question:**

Any idea how to make a .ics call from a webview in a iPhone application

Comment: Did you manage to open and save the .ics file in the calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use UIDocumentInteractionController and UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate delegated methods:
- Check if the clicked URL has .ics extension and use UIDocumentInteractionController to open using the appropriate external app.